# Dialogflow strange extracting parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a serious strange problem with dialogflow. Please see the following pictures:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

[image: pic4]

When I try this sentence "Let's set up a new FMR under fmr test with rents, studio at 1000, one bedroom at 1200, two bedroom rented at 1400, three bedroom priced at 1600 and four bedroom at 1800.", it only picks up some of "number"s.

Would you please help me on this to figure out why this happens? Is there any limitation in the number of dialogflow parameters now?

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is also a 255 character/symbol limit that might be causing the issue.

I just replicated your issue. However,  I get the proper result by removing "at" and some random short words.

[image: solution_image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have the same problem even when I copied your intent and user says exactly. Also in your above picture the "number4" value was extracted wrong and its value is "4" instead of "1800"

Comment: It is correct to be four not 1800. What is the “user says” phrase u tested with?

Comment: This is the phrase I have tested: "Let's set up a new FMR under fmr test with rents, studio at 1000,one bedroom at 1200, two bedroom rented at 1400, three bedroom prices at 1600 and four bedroom at 1800"  and unfortunately, "number4" is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add more "User Says" samples to train the engine a lot more. Also can you [use entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities) in your training. The results should be better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But the same example I sent you was working well for me about three weeks ago and now it does not work correctly.

Comment: Keep in mind you can always manually change the parameters for training phrases